# iOS custom Time Picker l

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, datetimepicker, timepicker

I want to create time picker in iOS like following image

[image]

Please suggest me any available framework or way to achieve this type of timer in iOS.

In this image when user click on red circle and drag to the number what he want to set.
For example In given image **currently it is 12 i.e 12:00AM** if I **dragged to 4** then Time should be **04:00 AM**

Comment: @Raj:You can draw the Clock using Quartz framework and can implement the touches in the Clock and modify other components according to the time selected by the user.

Comment: I think this could be created with the famous framework called UIKit

Comment: ohh thanks but this is available in google nexus 5 phone (i.e in Android KitKat OS) So just checking is there any available library in iOS

Comment: Don't use this picker. It's bad UI. With kind Regards, everyone who uses 24 hour time (i.e. most of the world).

Answer (score 4):

I was also in need of exactly same component so i created one.

Please check the below link...

Here's [**Link 2 Component**](https://github.com/ambhojgoyal/TimePicker)

I have given provision of theme in my project, for you requirement you need to set isDarkTheme to TRUE.

Hope this is as per expectations....

*Feel free to vote if you like my answer/Project.*

Answer (score 3):

Simple and pretty standard stuff can be done with little core graphics or UIDynamics for animation, present controller as model view

[image]

Comment: For what you need a library?

Comment: In Android For this picker there is a library. So just checking is there any similar in our iOS

Comment: I guess not so you can create one and take credit :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you were looking for this one - [ESTimePicker](https://github.com/e-sites/ESTimePicker). It is under BSD license, so you can use it in commercial projects...